# How to convert an 2D array specifically or any array into List<List<Integer>> in java 8?

Tags: java

Suppose there is an array `Integer[][] a;`
Then how to convert this `a` into `List<List<Integer>>` in java 8?
This is my code of leetcode Pascal's trianagle

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {

        Integer[][] a = new Integer[numRows][numRows];
        a[0][0] = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++) {
            a[i][0] = 1;
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                if(i == j) 
                    a[i][j] = 1;
                    else {
                        a[i][j] = a[i-1][j-1] + a[i-1][j];
                    }
            }
        }
       return ______;
    }
}
```

Now what should i write in return statement?

Comment: Rather than creating a 2D array and then convert it into a `List`, just create a `List` to begin with.

Comment: When I run this code I get an IndexOutOfBoundException where you call `a[i-1]` when i=0. The for loops should start with 1.

Answer (score 5):

This'll pass. We'd use an `ArrayList<>()` of type `List<List<Integer>` (which is the desired output) for all rows and just an `ArrayList<>()` for the temp row:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
        List<List<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            row.add(0, 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < row.size() - 1; j++)
                row.set(j, row.get(j) + row.get(j + 1));
            rows.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(row));
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

There is also a math Solution for Pascal's Triangle problem (e.g, in Python):

```
import math


class Solution:
    def generate(self, size):
        if size < 0:
            return [[1]]
        rows = []
        for n in range(size):
            row = []
            for r in range(n + 1):
                row.append(math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(r) // math.factorial(n - r))
            rows.append(row)
        return rows
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Using the lists is even better: the size of the row lists corresponds to the number of figures, where the int[][] contains [1,0,0,0,0].

Answer (score 2):

> how to convert a 2D array specifically or any array into List<List> in java 8?

If you use lists to begin with you wouldn't need to do the conversion.  But to answer your question for perhaps future reference, here is how you do it.

- A 2D array is an array of arrays.
- So the first stream, streams the arrays.
- the inner stream, streams the individual arrays and collects the values into a list.
- those lists are then once again collected into another List.

```
int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
        { 10, 11, 12, 13 } };
```

The first method returns the default implementation of list.

```
List<List<Integer>> list1 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(ar -> Arrays.stream(ar).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This method allows you to specify the `collection` type - in this case, an array list.

```
List<List<Integer>> list2 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(ar -> Arrays.stream(ar).boxed().collect(
                Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Prints

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```